# Homework: How much speedup is achieved when 40% of an application is parallelizable

Tags: performance, optimization, architecture, benchmarking

Upfront, here's the question:

"Your company will run two applications on a new dual core processor so that you may optimize the software for this processor.
A) Given that 40% of the first application is parallelizable, how much overall speedup would you achieve with that application if run in in isolation?"

I would assume that the 40% represents the "fractional enhanced" value for this program, so the old run-time of the parallelizable portion of the program was 2/5 the run-time of the entire program. (correct?)

Based on this, I need to find the "speedup enhanced" value to find the overall speedup of the program. How is it possible for me to find the speedup enhance value when I don't know the new run-time of the parallelizable portion of this program? (furthermore how am I supposed to find the speedup overall without that value?) Also I'm not sure what "the overall speedup" I would achieve when the application is "run in isolation" implies.

Does that mean I'm supposed to act as if this application is the only program running on the computer?

Comment: Open your copy of Hennessy and Patterson.  Turn to chapter one.  Find the section on "Amdahl's Law".

Comment: In each explanation of Amdahl's law in my book you need to know the new speed of the enhanced program to figure out the speedup overall. Today my professor has given me more versions of the equation that don't require certain variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is homework, I won't answer the original question directly, but I'll answer each of your individual questions, which is almost the same thing, just with more detail.

- *I would assume that the 40% represents the "fractional enhanced"
  value for this program, so the old run-time of the parallelizable
  portion of the program was 2/5 the run-time of the entire program.
  (correct?)*

Yes, I believe you are correct.

- *How is it possible for me to find the speedup enhance value when I
  don't know the new run-time of the parallelizable portion of this
  program?*

It is reasonable to assume that the new run-time of the parallelizable portion would be half the old run-time, since the load can now be shared by two processors. There will of course be some overhead, so in practice it will never be as low as half, but for the sake of homework, we can probably say it will be half.

- *furthermore how am I supposed to find the speedup overall without
  that value?*

Find the difference of the new run-time vs. the old. You don't need absolute values, you can just use percentages. 50% of 40% is 20%. The 60% of your program that is not parallelizable will be unchanged.

- *I'm not sure what "the overall speedup" I would achieve when the
  application is "run in isolation" implies.*

How much faster will your application run when you parallelize what can be parallelized on two processors vs. when the whole thing is run on a single processor?

- *Does that mean I'm supposed to act as if this application is the only
  program running on the computer?*

I believe that the prior statement of "run in isolation" implies that yes, this application will be the only program running on the computer. I think the original question's mention of two applications is a red herring if the first will be run in isolation anyway.

Comment: Thanks a ton, specifically being able to assume that the program will run twice as fast due to the two processors cleared this up for me. Much appreciated

Comment: Just to be clear, only the part of the program that can be parallelized can run (theoretically) twice as fast. And you're welcome!